# How to extract the whole executable and clear scripts from jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

Simply I build an `.ipynb` like this:

[image: test_jupyter]

And now I want to extract all python code from this `.ipynb` file. I have tried the `File->Download as->Python (.py)` menu function, and I get the following result:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[13]:

def a():
    la = [1, 2, 3]
    def b():
        print 'helloworld'
        print la, len(la)
    b()
a()


# In[1]:

get_ipython().magic(u'pylab inline')


# In[6]:

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


# In[8]:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# In[9]:

import numpy as np


# In[11]:

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)


# ### HelloWorld
# 1. kk
# 2. bb
# * jhah

# In[13]:


get_ipython().system(u'ipython nbconvert --to script test1.ipynb')


# In[ ]:
```

Is there any method to get the beautiful result (without `In [*]` and jupyter's magic function) like this?

```
# coding: utf-8

def a():
    la = [1, 2, 3]
    def b():
        print 'helloworld'
        print la, len(la)
    b()
a()


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import numpy as np


data = np.random.rand(2, 25)


# ### HelloWorld
# 1. kk
# 2. bb
# * jhah
```

Comment: Fromt he menu you can save your notebook as a Python script.

Comment: That does not get rid of `In [*]`, as the question says.

Answer (score 4):

You may have solved this by now. If not, you could use the `jupyter-nbconvert` script, which comes with Jupyter.

```
jupyter-nbconvert --to python notebook.ipynb --stdout --TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True
```

This will output your code only and get rid of the input prompts (`In [*]`).

There are [more options](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html) to exclude inputs, outputs, markdown, code and so on.

Tested in Jupyter 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that I have tried in the past and it worked for me:

1. Delete empty cells.
2. Select all the cells.
3. Convert all the cells type from `Code` to `Raw NB convert`.
4. Save the file in the `.py` format.

Voila you get your beautiful code in the desired format.